# Drop down for navigation bar not positioning in webpage

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm struggling with a part in my webpage, i can't get the drop down for the navigation bar to position properly... any ideas whats wrong? My html and CSS are in the link below. Thanks in advance :)

https://jsfiddle.net/cgc1L17n/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Futura", sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.drop{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.drop-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}

.drop-content a {
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}

.drop-content a:hover {
    background-color: #797980;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.drop:hover .drop-content {
    display: block;
}


.drop > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
}

.drop > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}


.nav {
    background-color: #696969;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 35px 0 35px;
}

.nav > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #696969;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.footer > a{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.text:hover{
    background: #797980;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 20px 25px 21px 25px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>GQFC</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="External.css"/>

</head>
<body>

<ul class = "nav">
    <li><a class = "text" href = "Home.html" value ="home">Home </a> </li>
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="quiz">Quiz </a> </li>
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="feedback">Feedback Form </a> </li>
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="gallery">Gallery </a> </li>
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="diagram">Diagram </a> </li>
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="shop">Shop </a> </li>
    <div class="drop">
    <li><a class = "text" href = "#" value ="shop">About Us </a> </li>
        <div class="drop-content">
            <a href="#">Gerald</a>
            <a href="#">Mohammad</a>
            <a href="#">Fatema</a>
            <a href="#">Chantel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</ul>


<div class="footer">This page was created by <a href = "#" value = "editor">Q</a><!-- CHANGE NAME HERE AND MAKE A HYEPERLINK TO UR CV --></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing your .text class and see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your .drop-content class you applied an absolute positioning but you still need to tweak the positioning a bit using left/right/top/bottom if needed. Remember this would be positioned to the .drop-content first relative positioned parent. In this case the .drop class.

```
.drop-content{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left:40px;
    top:40px;
}
```

Modify the left/top values above to get it how you want, along with adjusting the width if need be. The code above should get you on the right track.

For additional information on absolute positioning read: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @qudz Good to hear, can you select this as the answer please.